# firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword is exposing my email and password

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication

I am new to firebase and I was wondering why my email and password is being shown after signing in.

Why does it happen?
Is there any other way to hide this?

Image:

[image: this is the image]

Comment: I suggest you contact Google support, not much chance you'll get a definitive answer here

Answer (score 1):

Your browser will always be able to show you the data sent by API calls before they get encrypted and sent over the network.  There is not an issue at all.  This can't be used to see other people's passwords or network call details.

Comment: I might be wrong, but the order of the requests suggests that the password is being stored locally so it can be resent later.

Comment: so you mean it is ok that firebase is exposing these?

Comment: Firebase is not exposing them.  Your browser is exposing them. Firebase is doing everything it needs to do to be secure, and your browser is letting you peek in on what it's doing.

Comment: Oh well thank you for that but is there any way to solve this? cause browser is exposing them.

Comment: There's no problem to solve, because there's nothing insecure here.  Use a different browser if you want, but they all have developer tools that let you view the details of API requests.  As I said, this can't be used to view other people's passwords.  If you're using a shared computer, just be sure to close it after you're done.

Comment: I'll point out also that every single secure web site that allows password logins is going to reveal the same data at some point, no matter what they use for authentication.  The password **must** be sent via an API call like this at some point. There is no avoiding that.  The data sent encrypted, so no one else can see it.  That's just the way things work all around.